# App crashes when initializing view model (in fragment) that gets items from room database

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-room, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am currently building an app with a main activity that hosts a navHostFragment, and 2 fragments connected by a bottom navigation bar. One of the fragments uses a recyclerView that is meant to display items that display data from a room database. I am using the room database with an adapter and LiveData for the items. When I launch the app and go to this fragment it instantly crashes and after testing around I found out that it crashes when I try to use the viewModel in the code in any fragment and from the crash report I know the problem is in the application I use to hold the database. I am quite new at this so I don't know what the error is or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly apreciated.

**TaskHomeFragment**(Example fragment that initializes viewModel)

```
package com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.home

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.untitledcalendarapp.databinding.FragmentTaskHomeBinding
import com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.CalendarApplication
import com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.TaskListAdapter

class TaskHomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by activityViewModels{
        HomeViewModelFactory(
            (activity?.application as CalendarApplication).database.taskDao()
        )
    }
    private var _binding: FragmentTaskHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentTaskHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Create and bind Adapter
        val adapter = TaskListAdapter{ }
        binding.taskHomeGrid.adapter = adapter
        //observe items
        viewModel.allItems.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner){ items ->
            items.let{
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
        }
        //set layout manager
        binding.taskHomeGrid.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    }

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
package com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.home

import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.example.untitledcalendarapp.data.Task
import com.example.untitledcalendarapp.data.TaskDao


class HomeViewModel(private val taskDao: TaskDao): ViewModel() {
    //Get items from database
    val allItems: LiveData<List<Task>> = taskDao.getItems().asLiveData()


}
class HomeViewModelFactory(private val taskDao: TaskDao) : ViewModelProvider.Factory{
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(HomeViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return HomeViewModel(taskDao) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }

}
```

**Task** (entity)

```
package com.example.untitledcalendarapp.data

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.util.*

@Entity
data class Task(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    val taskTitle: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "desription")
    val taskDescription: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = " date")
    val taskDate: Date?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "priority")
    val taskPrio: Int
)
```

**TaskConverters** (Type converters)

```
package com.example.untitledcalendarapp.data

import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import java.util.*

class TaskConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return value?.let { Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time?.toLong()
    }
}
```

**TaskDao**

```
package com.example.untitledcalendarapp.data

import androidx.room.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow


@Dao
interface TaskDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from task ORDER BY title ASC")
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Task>>

    @Query("SELECT * from task WHERE id = :id")
    fun getItem(id: Int): Flow<Task>

    @Query("SELECT * from task ORDER BY priority DESC")
    fun getItemsByPrio(): Flow<List<Task>>
    // Specify the conflict strategy as IGNORE, when the user tries to add an
    // existing Item into the database.
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(task: Task)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(task: Task)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(task: Task)
}
```

**TaskRoomDatabase** (Database class)

```
package com.example.untitledcalendarapp.data


import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.room.TypeConverters

/**
 * Database class with a singleton INSTANCE object.
 */
@Database(entities = [Task::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(TaskConverters::class)
abstract class TaskRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun taskDao(): TaskDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE:TaskRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): TaskRoomDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    TaskRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "task_database"
                )
                    // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating if no Migration object.
                    // Migration is not part of this codelab.
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CalendarApplication** (Database Application)

```
package com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview

import android.app.Application
import com.example.untitledcalendarapp.data.TaskRoomDatabase


class CalendarApplication : Application(){
    val database: TaskRoomDatabase by lazy { TaskRoomDatabase.getDatabase(this) }
}
```

this is the crash report I get

```
2021-08-10 20:36:28.789 8076-8076/com.example.untitledcalendarapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.untitledcalendarapp, PID: 8076
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.CalendarApplication
        at com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.home.TaskHomeFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(TaskHomeFragment.kt:17)
        at com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.home.TaskHomeFragment$viewModel$2.invoke(TaskHomeFragment.kt:14)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:52)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.home.TaskHomeFragment.getViewModel(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.example.untitledcalendarapp.overview.home.TaskHomeFragment.onViewCreated(TaskHomeFragment.kt:39)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1971)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:341)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:276)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:7556)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:860)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8601)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8559)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8547)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1391)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1116)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollStep(RecyclerView.java:1838)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1940)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:3391)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$RecyclerViewImpl.onTouchEvent(ViewPager2.java:991)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3054)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2741)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
2021-08-10 20:36:28.790 8076-8076/com.example.untitledcalendarapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3060)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2755)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:465)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3993)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.tools.profiler.support.event.WindowProfilerCallback.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowProfilerCallback.java:61)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:423)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13674)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5482)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5285)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4947)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7505)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7474)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7435)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7630)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:188)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:178)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7581)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7654)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:718)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2021-08-10 20:36:28.806 8076-8076/com.example.untitledcalendarapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8076 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you add your `CalendarApplication` to the manifest file?

Comment: @Jarnojr Thanks I added it and it works now